# Get Property of SKSpriteNode in Touches

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to read a property off of a SKSpriteNode in the touchesBegan method but the property does not exist. Where as it does on the created object elsewhere.

```
 let enemy = enemy(imageName: "enemy.png",force: "12")
 addChild(enemy)
 enemy.name = "enemy"
 print (enemy.force) // 12

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation) as! SKSpriteNode
        if(touchedNode.name == "enemy"){
            print(enemy.force) //Force property does not exist
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NSDawg that worked if you answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: Hi James, it could be dangerous, what happen if you force casting to SKSpriteNode for not compatible sprites nodes, it might crash ... perhaps it is more convenient to avoid casting and after check the type of the node and decide what doing.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, yes I experienced that crash and fixed it shortly after. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that `SKSpriteNode` don't have a `force` property, you should use your class name that inherits `SKSpriteNode` properties (used to make `enemy`..)

An example could be this:

```
class Enemy : SKSpriteNode {
     var force: Int = 0
     ...
}
```

Then in your game scene do:

```
...
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)
    if(touchedNode.name == "enemy" && touchNode is Enemy){
       // Yes, I'm absolutely sure this is an enemy node..
       let enemy = touchedNode as! Enemy
       print(enemy.force)
    }
 }
```